# Rotating an image with the image centre as axis of rotation

Tags: cocoa

How can one image be rotated with axis of rotation as image centre using NSAffineTransform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to translate the origin to the point you want to rotate around, do the rotation and then translate the origin back:

```objectivec
@implementation NSAffineTransform (Rotation)
+ (NSAffineTransform *)transformRotatingAroundPoint:(NSPoint) p byDegrees:(CGFloat) deg
{
    NSAffineTransform * transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
    [transform translateXBy: p.x yBy: p.y];
    [transform rotateByDegrees:deg];
    [transform translateXBy: -p.x yBy: -p.y];
    return transform;
}
@end
```

Swift version for `CGAffineTransform` for use on iOS:

```swift
extension CGAffineTransform {
    static func rotationAround(point: CGPoint, byDegrees degrees: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform {
        CGAffineTransform()
            .translatedBy(x: point.x, y: point.y)
            .rotated(by: degrees * .pi / 180)
            .translatedBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I rotate the image when user moves touches on iphone? Any tutorial or code or URL or example?

Comment: A rotation around the center point will move (rotate) the origin as well. The solution you suggest does not move the origin at all. So something seems to be fishy.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the `translateXby:yBy:` method calls definitely move the origin point.